# Fortran Copying from Character Arrays

Tags: arrays, fortran, character

I have created an array of strings and want to assign the out put from the array values. A problem is occurring in that the information is not being copied over.

```
Block
  Character (Len=65), Allocatable :: typ(:)

  fa = "ftyp.org"
  Open (newunit=u, file=fa, form=human, action="read",  &
        status="old")

 Allocate (typ(nl))

 typ = ""
 Do i = 1, nl
   Read (u,"(a)") typ(i)
 End Do
 Close (u)

 a = Trim (typ(1))

 Write (*,*) "typ(1): ", Trim (typ(1))
 Write (*,*) "a:      ", Trim (a)
```

The output is as follows

```
typ(1): test_ftyp.org: ASCII text
a:
```

Comment: Can you supply us with all relevant declarations and make this a self-contained example?

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the problem. It occurred in the way I was calling the subroutine with optional arguments. The variable
`a` was an optional argument. I had called the routine without the optional argument, meaning that `a` was defaulted to the empty string.